# getting duplicates in 3sum problem using hashing

Tags: c++, algorithm, unordered-set

I was doing three sum problem [3SUM](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/)
I know better solution is to use two pointer.
But i gave it  a try with hashing I was able to solve the problem but I was 
getting duplicate triplets.
Although i tried to remove duplicates but still i was getting them.

```
// C++ program to find a triplet using Hashing 
#include <iostream>
#include<unordered_set>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>> output;
        unordered_set<int> seen;
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
            //removing duplicates
            if (i != 0 && nums[i] == nums[i - 1]) continue;

            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); ++j) {
                if (seen.count(-nums[i] - nums[j])) {
                    output.push_back({ nums[i], nums[j], -nums[i] - nums[j] });
                    // Skip duplicates
                    while (j + 1 < nums.size() && nums[j + 1] == nums[j]) ++j;
                }
                seen.insert(nums[j]);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
};



/* Driver program to test above function */
int main()
{
    vector<int> A = { -1,0,1,2,-1,-4 };
    int sum = 13;
    int arr_size = sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]);
    vector<vector<int>> v;

    Solution s;
    v=s.threeSum(A);
    //printing duplicates here
    for (auto p : v) {
        for (auto m : p) {
            cout << m<<" ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't check for `sum` first of all.

Comment: Think about what `seen` looks like after the first iteration through the outer loop ( `i`).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the ***unordered_set seen*** for all ***i*** which is causing duplicate triplets. Changing the scope of ***seen*** resolves the issue. Please find the correct code below.

```
vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<vector<int>> output;
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
            //removing duplicates
            if (i != 0 && nums[i] == nums[i - 1]) continue;
            unordered_set<int> seen; //changed the scope of seen
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.size(); ++j) {
                if (seen.count(-nums[i] - nums[j])) {
                    output.push_back({ nums[i], nums[j], -nums[i] - nums[j] });
                    // Skip duplicates
                    while (j + 1 < nums.size() && nums[j + 1] == nums[j]) ++j;
                }
                seen.insert(nums[j]);
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

The optimized way to solve this question will be using two-pointers without using any extra space.

```
vector<vector<int>> threeSum(vector<int>& nums) {
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
        int n = nums.size();
        vector<vector<int>> ret;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(i > 0 && nums[i] == nums[i-1]) continue;
            int j = i+1;
            int k = n-1;
            while(j < k)
            {
                if(nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0)
                {
                    ret.push_back({nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]});
                    while(j < k && nums[j] == nums[++j]);
                    while(j < k && nums[k] == nums[--k]);
                }
                else if(nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] < 0)
                    j++;
                else
                    k--;
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```